# Image grid working in all browsers except Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, microsoft-edge

I'm building a work portfolio site that features a responsive image grid on it's landing page. I wanted to include an image block that displayed 5 different pictures in quick succession when hovered over, so I decided to use the CSS animation function to "jump" from one point on a large rectangular image (4000 x 800, features five unique logos) to another.

Using CSS animation forced me to 'style' the animated block so that it would match the size of the other blocks at each breakpoint. This seemed to be working great in every browser I tested (Chrome, Firefox, Safari) except for Edge.

In Edge, this 'knocks' a block out of place, for reasons that are unclear to me.

Right now I'm wondering if I'll have to abandon CSS in lieu of a jQuery solution to achieve cross browser compatibility, so any advice/suggestions for solutions  would be appreciated!

Here's the Page in Chrome...
[image: How it looks in Chrome]

...and here's Edge
[image: How it looks in Edge]

The animated block is the one featuring the letter 'A'

Here's the CSS I used to get the 'A' block to fit with the rest at different breakpoints:

```
/*-- Logo Animation Hover Breakpoints --*/
@media (min-width: 1500px){
.logoswitch {
  background: url('../img/logo_thumb_bar.jpg');
  height: 448px;
  width: 448px;
  background-size: cover;
}

@keyframes play {
  100% { background-position: 2240px; }
}
#logohover:hover .logoswitch{
  -webkit-animation: notexistent;
  -moz-animation: notexistent;
  -o-animation: notexistent;
  -ms-animation: notexistent;
  animation: notexistent;
  -webkit-animation: play 2.5s steps(5) infinite;
  -moz-animation: play 2.5s steps(5) infinite;
  -o-animation: play 2.5s steps(5) infinite;
  -ms-animation: play 2.5s steps(5) infinite;
  animation: play 2.5s steps(5) infinite;
}
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) and (max-width: 1500px){
  .logoswitch {
  background: url('../img/logo_thumb_bar.jpg');
  height: 390px;
  width: 390px;
  background-size: cover;
}

@keyframes play {
  100% { background-position: 1950px; }
}
#logohover:hover .logoswitch{
 -webkit-animation: notexistent;
 -moz-animation: notexistent;
 -o-animation: notexistent;
 -ms-animation: notexistent;
 animation: notexistent;
 -webkit-animation: play 2.5s steps(5) infinite;
 -moz-animation: play 2.5s steps(5) infinite;
 -o-animation: play 2.5s steps(5) infinite;
 -ms-animation: play 2.5s steps(5) infinite;
 animation: play 2.5s steps(5) infinite;
 }
 }

 @media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1200px){
 .logoswitch {
 background: url('../img/logo_thumb_bar.jpg');
 height: 323.33px;
 width: 323.33px;
 background-size: cover;
 }

 @keyframes play {
 100% { background-position: 1616.65px; }
 }
 #logohover:hover .logoswitch{
 -webkit-animation: notexistent;
 -moz-animation: notexistent;
 -o-animation: notexistent;
 -ms-animation: notexistent;
 animation: notexistent;
 -webkit-animation: play 2.5s steps(5) infinite;
 -moz-animation: play 2.5s steps(5) infinite;
 -o-animation: play 2.5s steps(5) infinite;
 -ms-animation: play 2.5s steps(5) infinite;
 animation: play 2.5s steps(5) infinite;
 }
 }

 @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 992px){
 .logoswitch {
 background: url('../img/logo_thumb_bar.jpg');
 height: 250px;
 width: 250px;
 background-size: cover;
 }

 @keyframes play {
 100% { background-position: 1250px; }
 }
 #logohover:hover .logoswitch{
 -webkit-animation: notexistent;
 -moz-animation: notexistent;
 -o-animation: notexistent;
 -ms-animation: notexistent;
 animation: notexistent;
 -webkit-animation: play 2.5s steps(5) infinite;
 -moz-animation: play 2.5s steps(5) infinite;
 -o-animation: play 2.5s steps(5) infinite;
 -ms-animation: play 2.5s steps(5) infinite;
 animation: play 2.5s steps(5) infinite;
 }
 }

@media (max-width: 768px){
.logoswitch {
background: url('../img/logo_thumb_bar.jpg');
height: 50vw;
width: 50vw;
background-size: cover;
}

@keyframes play {
100% { background-position: 250vw; }
}
#logohover:hover .logoswitch{
-webkit-animation: notexistent;
-moz-animation: notexistent;
-o-animation: notexistent;
-ms-animation: notexistent;
animation: notexistent;
-webkit-animation: play 2.5s steps(5) infinite;
-moz-animation: play 2.5s steps(5) infinite;
-o-animation: play 2.5s steps(5) infinite;
-ms-animation: play 2.5s steps(5) infinite;
animation: play 2.5s steps(5) infinite;
}
}
```

Comment: Temporary Solution I'm using as of 15 minutes ago: reducing the height at all breakpoints (save for the smallest which uses 'vw') by one pixel. Doesn't cause any easily discernible difference.

Comment: I'm an engineer on the Microsoft Edge team. I would love if you could link to a non-patched version of this, so that we can compare the experience between major browsers, and see if we need to make any changes to our implementation(s).